# CIFS Mount fail - mount:bad usage or mount.cifs: bad UNC (/192.168.68.57/TrueNAS)

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs, nas

I’m a newb, but here I go. I’m running Ubuntu Server 23.10 and I have been trying to mount a NAS to it for days. Right up front I should mention that I have GNOME desktop installed and I can see as well as MOUNT any of the 4 shares using the GUI, but I want to be able to do this from the command line via SSH for example. I feel like I have been to the ends of the internet for clues, but nothing seems to work. At this point I am also wondering if I’m missing something very fundamental, like, “Oh you can’t do that”.

The NAS is PC based, running TrueNAS-SCALE-22.12.3.1. and there are 4 “Windows (SMB) Shares” on it. It’s ip address is 192.168.68.63 and if I ping it with “truenas.local” I get a proper response. `PING truenas.local (192.168.68.63) 56(84) bytes of data.`

My fstab file contains this line: `/192.168.68.63/TrueNAS /mnt/nas cifs username=slingshot,password=bur$t,workgroup=WORKGROUP,iocharset=utf8 0 0`

When I run: `mount – a`, I get this error: `mount.cifs: bad UNC (/192.168.68.63/TrueNAS)`

When I run: `mount -t cifs //192.168.68.63/SFX /mnt/nas -o username=slingshot,password=bur$t,workgroup=WORKGROUP iocharset=utf8`
I get this error: `mount: bad usage`

When I run: `smbclient -L 192.168.68.63`
I get all of this (correct) information:

```
Sharename             Type      Comment
---------             ----      -------
IPC$                  IPC       IPC Service (TrueNAS Server)
WORK_BAK              Disk      Sessions and Projects BAK
SFX                   Disk      Sound Effects
MACHINE_TIME          Disk      NONE
NATIVE_CONTENT        Disk      Sample Libraries
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
```

I’ve run `nmap` and gotten this:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.68.63
Host is up (0.0015s latency).
Not shown: 991 closed tcp ports (reset)
  
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
179/tcp  open  bgp
443/tcp  open  https
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
5357/tcp open  wsdapi
6000/tcp open  X11
9001/tcp open  tor-orport
MAC Address: E0:3F:49:86:1C:EA (ASUSTek Computer)
```

I am a bit confused about specifying cifs or smb3.
Here are some other facts:

```
Samba version 4.18.6-Ubuntu

cifs-utils:
  Installed: 2:7.0-2
  Candidate: 2:7.0-2
  Version table:
 *** 2:7.0-2 500
```

Any thoughts would be welcome, I'm at wits end. Cheers.

Comment: The first thing you could do would be to try and add quoting to prevent Bash variable expansion, and replace the space with a comma you probably want: `mount -t cifs //192.168.68.63/SFX /mnt/nas -o 'username=slingshot,password=bur$t,workgroup=WORKGROUP,iocharset=utf8'`

Comment: "My fstab file contains this line: `/192.168.68.63/`"? Did you forget one of the two slashes that are supposed to be at the start of the line?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @ Daniel T your suggested change to the command yielded and interesting result: `mount.cifs: permission denied: no match for /mnt/nas found in /etc/fstab`. However, I did stumble upon something that did work, which I will describe in an answer to my own question.

Comment: If it says "permission denied" have you tried adding sudo, i.e. replace "mount" with "sudo mount"?

Comment: Interesting @Daniel T, I just tried adding sudo and got this response: `mount error(79): Can not access a needed shared library` which makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have two unrelated problems:

> UPDATE: I successfully mounted the share with the following simplified
> command: sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.68.63/SFX /mnt/nas -o
> username=slingshot I removed:
> ,password=bur$t,workgroup=WORKGROUP,iocharset=utf

If you want this to automount with an entry in fstab you need to create a credentials file.

** Create a file at **/etc/samba/creds/SFX** with this content:

```
username=slingshot
password=bur$t
```

***Note: There can be no spaces in either line.***

** Then your manual mount becomes:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.68.63/SFX /mnt/nas -o credentals=/etc/samba/creds/SFX,iocharset=utf
```

And an fstab entry would look like this:

```
//192.168.68.63/SFX /mnt/nas cifs credentials=/etc/samba/creds/SFX,iocharset=utf 0 0
```

In both cases I suspect you will need to modify permissions but that's up to you.

> Note that sudo mount -a still results in mount.cifs: bad UNC
> (/192.168.68.63/TrueNAS)

You have 2 problems here:

It says you have a bad UNC ( syntax ) because you only have one / instead of two. It should have been **//192.168.68.63/TrueNAS**

The second problem is that according to the output of smbclient -L above you **have no share labeled TrueNAS** so I suggest you stop trying to mount it and remove the line from fstab.

Comment: Thank you @Morbius1 - I finally got my fstab into shape and am now mounting several shares at boot time to my Desktop using the following: `//truenas.local/SFX /home/slingshot/Desktop/SFX cifs credentials=/home/slingshot/.credentials,iocharset=utf8 0 0` and `//truenas.local/WORK_BAK home/slingshot/Desktop/WORKBACK cifs credentials=/home/slingshot/.credentials,iocharset=utf8 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I successfully mounted the share with the following simplified command: `sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.68.63/SFX /mnt/nas -o username=slingshot`
I removed: `,password=bur$t,workgroup=WORKGROUP,iocharset=utf`
And with my fstab file unchanged, I was prompted for the password of the share and it mounted. Note that `sudo mount -a` still results in `mount.cifs: bad UNC (/192.168.68.63/TrueNAS)`. That is progress, but leaves me wondering if the $ character in my NAS password is what is causing problems. Next I shall try doing this with a .credentials file. FWIW, I found this guide to be quite helpful: https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/linux-mount-smb-share/

Comment: Hello, have you tried to quote the password?